# How to target only outgoing links in HTML

Tags: html

I want to force all outgoing links on my site to open in a new tab with some simple `<header>` code. I know you can force *all* links to open in a new tab with this code in the `<header>` tag:

```
<base target='_blank' />
```

But I only want to target outgoing links (so that a link to another page on my site will NOT be opened in a new tab). Anyway to do this? I feel like there has to be...

Answer (score 4):

I did this using Javascript on my site. I found it easier to parse all my links when the page loads and add the `_blank` target programmatically instead of manually adding the attribute to links. (Bonus: tampering with the `target` attribute in JS lets your code [validate](http://validator.w3.org/))

I used JQuery on my site, but the logic is pretty straightforward:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    parseLinks();
});

function parseLinks()
{
    // Manage external links
    $("a").each(function()
    {
        if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf("://") >= 0)
        {
            $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
        }
    });
}
```

If you don't want to use JQuery:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    parseLinks();
};

function parseLinks()
{
    // Manage external links
    var Links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < Links.length; i++)
    {
        if (Links[i].href.indexOf("://") >= 0)
        {
            Links[i].target = "_blank";
        }
    }
}
```

I put it in a function so you can call `parseLinks` whenever you need to re-run the code (AJAX calls, after user interaction, etc.)

Comment: I think you can use the selector a[href], meaning any `<a>` with a non-empty `href` attribute.  You might want to work harder to exclude in-page links like `<a href="#nav">`.

Comment: @Eric: I am pretty sure he ignores any `href`s that do not contain `://`.

Comment: True. I still think the `a[href]` selector is better.

Comment: But it adds the attribute to anchor links with `#page` `hrefs` too.